# Project EF Core 7 result to named tuple

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I'm using EF Core 7. I want to perform server evaluation and project to a named tuple.

I tried:

```cs
var products = await _context.Products.Select(x => (x.Id, x.Name)).ToListAsync();
```

Which gives:

> An expression tree may not contain a tuple literal.

I could do this with a regular tuple (`Tuple.Create()`) or an anonymous object (`new {}`), but I'd like to use a named tuple, if possible.

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: You’ll have to do it after the query results return. (After tolistaaync)

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes that's what I'm doing now, converting from an anonymous type to a named tuple after the await. I was hoping there was a friendlier way to do it. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Nope. There’s no way to extend the Expression trees, so it’s left incomplete/broken with new language features

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, currently it is not possible because it is not possible to use value tuples literals in the expression trees. You can monitor following issues/discussions at the github:

- [[Proposal]: Expression tree evolution](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/4727)
- [Expression trees support for tuples.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12897)

If you really-really want to use value tuples the only way is to map to them after the materialization of the query, but I would argue that it is rather pointless in most cases. Something like the following:

```cs
var products = _context.Products
   .Select(x => new {x.Id, x.Name})
   .AsEnumerable()
   .Select(ac => (ac.Id, ac.Name))
   .ToList();
```

Though there is a trick with method indirection which can be used:

```cs
class SomeClass // local functions can't be used
{
    public static (int Id, int Name) CreateNamedValueTuple(int t1, int t2) => (t1, t2);
}

var products = await _context.Products
    .Select(x => SomeClass.CreateNamedValueTuple(x.Id, x.Name))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Though personally I would just used a C# 9 [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) feature which allows easy type creation (or C# 10 [record struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/record-structs)).

Answer (score 1):

You actually can use `ValueTuple.Create()` in your Select expression. EFCore will do the right thing.

```
var products = await _context.Products.AsNoTracking()
    .Select(x => ValueTuple.Create(x.Id, x.Name))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Of course, you'll have to encapsulate this in a function that returns a IEnumerable<(int Id, int Name)> as suggested by Guru Stron's answer.